# Eclipse cvs merge issue, merge act as compare

Tags: eclipse, merge, cvs

How can I resolve this merging issue ?

My project has 1 branch which I used for production and head. 2 times it worked merging production branch into head. Each time I created a tagged head after merging to have a start point for the next merge. Its important to note that I do not create a new branch after each merge, I reuse the branch.

The problem is, if I try to merge my branch to head. eclipse cvs acts like it is comparing and listing all files as "to update", even if file head version is greater than the file branch version.

ex: head file version is 1.8 and branch file version is 1.6. This file was already merged in last merge. When trying to merge I specifiy as "common base version" the head tag that I created after the last merge. Still, eclipse cvs suggests to override head modifications and use the branch version. This behaviour applies to all files.

I dont know what to do. I dont want to manually merge hundreds of files.

thanks for any help

Comment: I didn't get your point. Here is where I'm confused. You develop new code on trunk or the branch? So your merge is from trunk -> branch or branch -> trunk?

Comment: I develop new code in trunk and in branch. Trunk is for main development. I also develop on production branch, mainly for bug correction, but also for little features. I merge branch-trunk always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example:

```
                  |tag_h1    |tag_h2
 -----------------------------------------> trunk
      \          ^           ^
       \        /           /
        \----------------------------------> my_branch
              |tag_b1      |tag_b2
```

On branch there are tags `tag_b1` and `tag_b2` before each merge, and in trunk, tags `tag_h1` and `tag_h2`.

For a next merge from branch to trunk, the "common base version" of Eclipse will be the one tagged with `tag_b2`. With CVS update, if you specify two parameters, you will get modifications between these two merged in your working directory. Giving `Branch or version to be merged (end tag)=my_branch` and `Common base version (start tag)=tag_b2` will merge changes from `tag_b2` until `my_branch` end, like calling CVS from command line:

`$ cvs up -j tag_b2 -j my_branch`

I always tag from where I will merge, and before and after the merge, like this:

```
       |tag_before        |tag_after
---------------------------------> 
                    ^
                   /
    ------------------------------>
               |tag_from
```

Giving the tags a name I can recognize.